# Creating a shell script programmatically in Windows and running it on a Linux system via cygwin?

Tags: windows, linux, shell, cross-platform, sh

I want to write a shell script in Windows e.g., `myscript.sh` and then connect to a Linux machine via cygwin and ssh, and execute the script. I've used  dos2unix to convert .sh files that were created in windows to run under Linux. Obviously if I am executing a script with ssh  it will have to be Linux formatted to work, so I need to know how to create a Linux supprted script using C, OpenOffice basic or vBA?

Are there any recommended methodologies, guides or tutorials you can share with me to demonstrate how to do this?

Comment: This "master" program, do you intend to launch it as a windows GUI or would you launch it from cygwin?

Comment: If `dos2unix` is already working for you, why do you need more? Any decent editor will  have different encoding options. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.0.html) has it.

Answer (score 1):

just make sure you used ascii encoding and set line separator to be newline only in your output.

i have done this but use powershell instead, which has encoding option for output file.